# Facebook via login not returning Token in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, callback, facebook-login, omniauth

I have configured Facebook via login using this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/integrating-social-login-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application) and it's working fine. I'm able to send a login call at Facebook and after users acknowledgment, it's redirect to my site. However, In the callback URL, only "code" is returning but I required an access token.

Here is my code.

```
Devise.rb  
  config.omniauth :facebook, "client_id", "secret", scope: 'public_profile,email,manage_pages,read_insights',:display => 'popup'

  User.rb  
  devise  :database_authenticatable,:registerable,:recoverable, 
        :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
        :confirmable,:lockable,:timeoutable,
        :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

  def self.current
    Thread.current[:user]
  end
  def self.current=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end

  def self.create_from_provider_data(provider_data)
    where(provider: provider_data.provider, uid: provider_data.uid).first_or_create do | user |
      user.email = provider_data.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end
   
   omniauth controller  
   def facebook
         @user = User.create_from_provider_data(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        if @user.persisted?
            sign_in_and_redirect @user
            set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format?
        else
            user = User.create!(email: auth.info.email,
                       password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                       user_name: auth.info.first_name
                       )
            user.authentications.create!(user_id: user.id,
                                                provider: auth.provider,
                                                uid: auth.uid)
            flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in through Facebook. Please register or try signing in later.'
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end 
    end

    def failure
        flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in. Please register or try signing in later.' 
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
```

CallBack Response:

Parameters: {"code"=>"AQBBtixd3nmIkT_KyKUKmy68hBYt7kdZ0jX1pATNmDCSWmjfoiAC_8C5aOF3P3jKRyhKYX2JfL0gZDWZCTraN_kdZpxIJu8pYWkktr0E9Q2WXk6xjz0Uyz4cS2YeTv0SyqjZbZvQr8roxKCPvZb-6UKbCzMGZsi3-VLXK3suPfs729nR8MilmuatZqQ-TanApTy-8Qh195ntqfD6gIMhbZZMBhAuVSbf6GmyT-anNV0exczDMzKIF6OpZoIFC7Vxez8EH3cR7BUPqc5OldfbDD8j9pY6kDeoc00An9wuGj4hAfne_jeShUZTw_zSQMmxkbMqe2acFPJWE5DLL2QNII54", "state"=>"c231b221dba5bdc33fff6349af5793c0cbb5bdcc69253372"}

As per this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/), we can get required information from callback response.

How i can update my code to get access token.

Answer (score 0):

You can to send another request with the code to get the access token.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch email and other details by `request.env['omniauth.auth']['info']['email']`.

As I can see you are using `auth.info.email` and auth is not defined due to which error persist.